# Django, Don't save the form to the base

Tags: python, django

I am doing my first project in Django and I am having 2 problems, I cannot figure out why the form is not being saved. It seems that I do everything according to the documentation. It does not give out obvious errors. And why empty_label doesn't apply

Tried using different form forms.Form and ModelForm, but unsuccessfully (

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Cars(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Автомобиль', default='МЭ')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Автомобиль'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Автомобили'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Trip(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, verbose_name='Дата')
    car = models.ForeignKey(Cars, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автомобиль')
    start_work = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Начало работы')
    finish_work = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Окончание работы')
    hours_worked = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name='Отработано часов')
    deal_me = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Сделки МЭ', blank=True, default=0)
    deal_gts = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Сделки ГТС', blank=True, default=0)
    gain = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Выручка', null=True, default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Доставка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Достваки'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Cars, Trip


class TripForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ['car', 'date', 'start_work', 'finish_work', 'deal_me', 'deal_gts', 'gain']

        car = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cars.objects.all(), empty_label="Выберите автомобиль", required=True)
        date = forms.DateField(required=True)
        start_work = forms.TimeField(required=True)
        finish_work = forms.TimeField(required=True)
        deal_me = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
        deal_gts = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
        gain = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

        widgets = {
            'car': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'custom-select'}),
            'date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
            'start_work': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'time'}),
            'finish_work': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'time'}),
            'deal_me': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'number'}),
            'deal_gts': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'number'}),
            'gain': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'number'}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import TripForm
from .models import Trip


def home_view(request):
    trip = Trip.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'driver_productivity/home.html', {'trip': trip})


def add_trip(request):
    form = TripForm()

    if request.method == 'post':
        form = TripForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    return render(request, 'driver_productivity/add.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from driver_productivity.views import home_view, add_trip

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('add/', add_trip, name='add'),
]
```

Comment: The `request.method` will always be [uppercase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method), so your view is not actually handling the POST request.

Comment: It turned out) Thank you very much!